# How to define yasnippet templates using elisp instead of the file system?

Tags: yasnippet

I would like to use YASnippet template system to expand abbreviations. (I don't want to use abbrev-mode which use space or symbols for expansion.)

It is not convenient to create a new file for each of my abbreviation.  Could I define yasnippet templates using elisp (in init.el) instead of using the YASnippet files structure?

Comment: You might be interested in https://github.com/Kungsgeten/yankpad

Comment: Thank for the pointer.  It looks good, but I found a simpler approach recently.  So I will answer my question below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Source: https://web.archive.org/web/20080319085637/http://code.google.com/p/yasnippet/wiki/HowtoDefineSnippet

You can use yas-define-snippets to define a bunch of snippet for a mode at a time. The basic syntax is:

```
(yas-define-snippets MODE SNIPPETS)
```

Here's an example:

```
(yas-define-snippets 'text-mode
  '(("email" "`user-mail-address`" "User's email address")
    ("time" "`(current-time-string)`" "Current Time")
    ("foo" "blablablabla")))
```

Comment: That web page is obsolete, `yas/define` no longer exists, and the syntax for `yas-define-snippets` is different

Comment: Let me remove `yas/define`. Thanks.  Btw, I am using `(yas-define-snippets ...)` which still works for me.

Comment: Oh you are right, the definition of `yas-define-snippets` is different.  I updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
(use-package yasnippet-snippets
  :defer 2
  :hook (prog-mode . yas-minor-mode)
  :config
  (yas-define-snippets 'js-mode
                       '(("clg" "console.log('$1: %s (%s)',$2);" "pX console.log()")
                         ("cle" "console.error('$1: %s (%s)',$2);" "pX console.error()")
                         ("Js" "JSON.stringify($1)" "pX JSON Stringification")
                         ("i" "if ($1) {\n$2\n\t} else {\n$3\n\t}\n" "Standard if")
                         ("time" "`(current-time-string)`" "Current Time")
                         ("if" "if ($1) {\n\t$2\n}" "pX if")))
  (yas-define-snippets 'sh-mode
                       '(("if" "if [ $1 ] ; then\n\t$2\nelse\n\t$3\nfi " "pX if"))))
```

Optional:

```
(use-package company
  :defer 2
  :after prog-mode
  :hook (prog-mode . company-mode)
  :bind (:map company-active-map
          ([(tab)] . company-auto-complete))
  :custom
  (company-dabbrev-ignore-case t)
  (company-etags-ignore-case t)
  (company-selection-wrap-around t)
  (company-minimum-prefix-length 1)
  (company-idle-delay 0.0)
  :config
  (eval-after-load 'company
    '(add-to-list 'company-backends '(company-yasnippet company-dabbrev-code company-capf))))
```